# Git shows differences even after `push --force`?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Simplification :

[image]

In my `master` branch I've added some garbage.
Then I pushed it to origin/master

Later I've discovered that it was a mistake to add that garbage.
I know I can/should create a revert commit.

But I didn't. I did a `git  reset --hard`

[image]

But now I want that the origin/master will look exactly the same as my local.

Obviously I can't push becuase git tells me to `pull` before push.

So I did `push --force`:

[image]

But even after that , sourcetree shows that they are not the same :

[image]

Even though if I check for changes , I see no changes :

[image]

**Question:**

If remote `master` and local `master` has no differences , why does sourcetree show me   `pull` ?

[image]

Even `git status` shows I'm ok (without pull) :

[image]

Comment: Maybe its problem with sourcetree. You can reopen sourcetree and check.

Comment: @unreleased Indeed. Reopen - solved it. please post it as an answer so it can be helpful to others.

Comment: No need to close and reopen, just refresh with `F5` or `⌘`+`R`.

Comment: Windows version of SourceTree sucks (on Mac it works as it should). On Windows I'm using and recommending `Git Extentions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SourceTree checks the remote status periodically.

**Solution 1**: Simply reopen the Sourcetree

**Solution 2**: *Tools>Options>General* check default remotes for updates every X minutes. 
 Make the X to 1/2 to get to see the status change faster. Like as the image you can see the updated status after 1 minute.

[image: change remote update time]

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

General advice: whenever a GUI that wraps a CLI program or library seems to misbehave, it is a good idea to check directly with the actual CLI program or library.

---

In this case, running a fetch:

```
git fetch origin
```

And then checking where the branches point to using:

```
git log master origin/master
```

Or perhaps:

```
git branch --all --verbose
```

Or even:

```
git show master
git show origin/master
```

allow you to check to which commit (hash) the branches actually point, and therefore confirm (or not) whether the GUI has a problem.

Even if you confirmed that SourceTree does not show the issue when reopening it, I would double-check with Git directly, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Sourcetree gets out of sync with your local repository. When this happens, simply tell Sourcetree to refresh its view with <kbd>F5</kbd> (Windows) or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (macOS).